# Renew local repository files from server

Tags: git, github

I had latest repository in my directory. Then I have deleted file. Now I need this file back. I have executed following command to get everything from repository:

`git pull origin master`

But this not helped - "evrything is up to date".

How to solve file recovery problem in GIT way?

Comment: are you certain that the file you deleted was under version control? what is the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 3):

Type

```
git status
```

then, if you see something like this

> deleted:   file.ext

just discard your changes.

Use `git checkout -- file.ext` to discard changes for one file or use `git checkout -- .` to discard all